Blocking diodes with solar panels
Why would you not place a blocking diode on the negative line of the PV panel, which could be connected in different parallel strings, which have 8 or more panels in a series string?
If the charging voltage electron flow moves in reverse flow, would it not be a safer bet to install blocking diodes on both lines?

it is unclear what you are asking ... please draw a diagram

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You don't need diodes on both lines. One blocking diode in one line (makes no difference if it's the positive or negative) is sufficient.

Word of advice: the sooner you forget everything about "electron flow", the sooner you will understand how electricity works. Current is current is current. And current flows from positive to negative in a load; the other way in a source. The sooner you start thinking of current that way,  the sooner you will understand how electricity works.

I know what current is, however, without the flow of electrons one will not have current flow. principle to think on. Thanks for you're input. There is a reason why I am asking this question and hope the viewers have the same question in mind. Regards
Lawrence

It's ok to think about electron flow too - you actually have to when studying semiconductor physics. And what is a PV panel but a device that converts photons to electrons.

FWIW: Diodes waste power. Not a lot, but maybe enough that you don't want to use more diodes than you need to do the job. A rectifier diode that is conducting 10A could be burning between 5 and 10 Watts—between 1.25% and 2.5% of the power generated by a 400W solar module.

Suppose you have a PV installation consisting of:

N series strings of say 8 panels
Each string is connected via wires of appropriate cross section to busbars, thus all strings are in parallel

If one panel gets shorted, for example due to damage, the following occurs:

Open circuit voltage on this panel's string drops by the voltage the panel used to generate, and corresponds to 7 still operational panels.
Open circuit voltage on all other strings remains the same, corresponding to 8 panels voltage.

Thus, in the string with the shorted panel, the non-defective panels will receive excessive voltage. They behave as diodes (because PV cells are diodes) so the non-defective panels will conduct and sink all the current from the N-1 other strings. Thus:

Wires were sized for the current of 1 string now pass the current of N-1 strings,. If N=2 that's okay, but above that, they will overheat and start a fire.

Functional panels in the defective string will also overheat and possibly burn.


When paralleling strings, it is true that placing diodes in series with each string will prevent this. Since this is a series configuration, the diode can be placed anywhere in series and it will work the same: positive or negative wire.
However, legislation usually does not consider semiconductors appropriate for safety devices. This is because quite often, when they fail, they fail shorted. In this case the failure would also be silent: with a shorted diode, the parallel combination of strings would work fine until one panel gets shorted by damage. Then the shorted diode wouldn't do its job.
That's why the standard protection measure when paralleling more than 2 strings is to use one fuse per string, to protect against the failure mode outlined above.

Indeed! Thanks!
